# PHP: test == return false when he should not

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm working with symfony2, and i really don't understand what's happen with this.
 i have a == test, who don't return true when he should !At the very first iteration of that foreach, the == 's for test answer one time true, but after the first foreach iteration he don't find the other match... I had tried a lot of var_dump, and the var_dump say that: $service->getId()  is  int(24),  and $discountsID is int(24), but the == test isn't true.

So help me, i'm pretty noob with php, and i really don't get what's happen there..

```
foreach ($services as $service) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($discountsID); ++$i) { 
        if ($service->getId() == $discountsID[$i]) { //the fail test..
            $bool = $discounts[$i]->getId();
        } else {
            $bool = -1;
        }
    } 

    $view_data['services'][] = array(
        'discountId' => bool,
    );
}
```

Comment: When he should not? How do you know **PHP** is male?

Comment: Your array is wrong; you're setting the value to `bool` instead of `$bool`

Comment: I enjoyed `var_dumb()` !!!

Comment: Does it work for any variable in the loops or just fail with everyone?

Comment: @phpNoOb not everyone's first language is english. give the guy a break; this is a programming site not an english usage site.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to include a condition in your for that terminates the loop where your if condition is reached.  Many persons don't like break (neither I do) but this would work:

```
if( $service->getId() == $discountsID[$i] ){ //the fail test..
    $bool = $discounts[$i]->getId();      
    break;
}
```

Comment: ho god !!!!!! thanks sooooo muchhhh brooooo.  Thanks to you i haven understand my probleme. HAHAHAHAHA, so noob mistake ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Above the test, add this:

```
var_dump($service->getId()); 
var_dump($discountsID[$i]); 
die();
```

And see if the outcome matches

Also this seems wrong to me:

```
foreach ($services as $service) {
$service->getId()
```

What does `$services` consist of?

Comment: yes, bool is $bool in my project.
 I have done those tests, and i have seen match answer. But the == return false..
 $services is a list of some service.
 $discounts is a list of discount.
 And one service can have one discount.

 I want to give to this array those discount's ID (if the service have one)

Comment: If you have seen a 100% match, then the if statement won't be wrong. Like said above, `'discountId' => bool,` should be `'discountId' => $bool,`. This could be the error.